# Differences between BSD ports and Debian apt

Tags: apt, dependencies, bsd-ports

I read recently that installing dependencies in Linux, let's say through apt for example, is quite different from BSD style ports. (And I guess MacPorts borrows from this style?) But I'm not entirely clear on the differences. Apologies if this question is too open ended, but I thought this might be an okay place to get some explanation.

Comment: apt uses binary packages called `deb` files; and was the first widely used dependency manager in linux. BSD ports is an entirely different style of packaging, more akin to [gentoo](https://packages.gentoo.org/) than to `deb`(s).

Comment: So `deb`s are pre-compiled binaries, while ports are pure source built on the target machine?

Comment: The original FreeBSD ports was entirely source based (as far as I can recall), but now there are also binary [*packages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports) (which makes it a little complicated to describe, but ultimately more user friendly). There are also *source packages* (deb-src) on debian derived systems. Open source software usually includes an easy way to get at the source.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please make into an answer to get points.